# Set Background Image for a Shape drawn by Canvas

Tags: android, shapes

The goal is to draw some hexagons on the screen and set different background images for those hexagons (I'm making a broad game). I have read about the `Shape` in XML file, but i want to draw it programmatically. I have drawn a shape with the help of canvas like this:

```
Path hexPath = hex.getPath();
canvas.clipPath(hexPath);
canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
```

how can i set up the background image for this shape ?

I also have read about **cropping a Bitmap**, but is not practical for me.

Thanks.